nodeJs mysql connection can't end before other queries finished
I am using nodeJs with the mysql package to query my database. The thing is that after creating the connection I query for some rows and forEach row I need to do some operations that include also new sql queries. I am using the mysql without promises but only callbacks. so within the first query I have a callback that triggers multiple other queries. When can I end the connection without getting the error Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit?
This is my code
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({whatever});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query('first query that returns a set of rows',function(err,result){
        if(err) throw err;
        result.forEach(element => {
            con.query('second query that runs multiple times')
        })
    })
    con.end();
})

I am sorry if there already is an answer to this question but I couldn't find it. Thanks for the help in advance!
I tried ending the connection after the first query (not within the callback) and I expected it to end. but apparently the ending process is put before the second queries who are in the callback of the first. Do I need to establish a new connection (end the previous one and connect again) for each of the queries in order for this to work?

con.query is async. if you now run con.query() in a forEach and you don't take care of that async behaviour you are executing multiple queries at the same time on the same connection which is not possible. Furhtermore because it's outside of the callback, con.end() is called way before any of the queries finished. I'd strongly suggest to refactor your code to uses Promises and make use of async / await

@derpirscher thanks I will restructure with async/await
